# Jersey Multiple Produces

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I am following the jersey tutorial [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2089) to figure out how one would produce multiple mime outputs. From their website, this is the recommended way:

```
@GET
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public String doGetAsXmlOrJson() {
    ...
}
```

What I cannot figure out is how to abstract the @Produces away, so that my code is more welcoming to additional mime types it can produce. Say for example I have 500 methods that all have this annotation:

```
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
```

If I get a requirement to add kml as a mime type, editing and replacing all of those values would certainly be time consuming.

```
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json", "application/kml"})
```

Is it possible to architect @Produces more efficiently so that I do not have this issue down the road?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Understanding the `@Produces` annotation

The [`@Produces`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Produces.html) annotation is used to specify the MIME media types of representations a resource can produce and send back to the client.

The JAX-RS runtime compares value of the [`Accept`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2) header of an incoming request with the value of the [`@Produces`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Produces.html) annotation to match the resource method that will handle such request.

In the absence of the [`@Produces`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Produces.html) annotation, support for any media type (`*/*`) is assumed. For a complete reference, check the [JAX-RS specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf).

### What you can do

To reduce the amount of [`@Produces`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Produces.html) annotations in your code, you could annotate the *resource classes* instead of annotating the *resource methods*.

---

**Tip:** To reduce typographical errors you could use constant values:

```java
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
```

Have a look at the [`MediaType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html) class.

Comment: great! exactly what I was looking for! I could not for the life of me find the "support all media" like you mentioned initially. ty